# Use of Excel 2011 to produce a line graph showing amplitude variations with distance

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, charts

I have 2 columns of numbers:

- Column A I want to be the X axis of a smooth line graph which goes through all of the data points which shows distance.
- Column B I want to be the Y axis showing amplitude.

Instead of Column A as the X axis, I get a linear scale which does not truly represent the information I am trying to portray. Is there any way of achieving my needs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Excel 2007, so YMMV, but have you tried an "**X Y (Scatter)**" chart?
[image: Excel "Change Chart Type" dialog]

For example,
[image: example chart resulting from above choice]